# Prove that $\left | f(x) - a \right | \leq \frac{1}{2} \left | x - a \right |$

Tags: functions, inequality, real-numbers, absolute-value

$f(x) = 1 - \frac{1}{x}(\sqrt{1 + x^2}-1)$

$|f'(x)| \leq \frac{1}{2}$

$a$ is a solution for $f(x) = x$ where  $0.65 < a < 0,7$

The question says:

Prove that $\left | f(x) - a \right | \leq \frac{1}{2} \left | x - a \right |$

I have no idea from where to begin, if I knew I would have posted my attempt at a solution but I didn't even know how to start it.

Any ideas?

Comment: While stating a problem, try to pose it in a decent manner so that everybody can understand. The problem is very ill-posed.

Comment: @Kolmogorov Okay. Suggest what I can improve and I will do it. W

Comment: Did you find out that $f'(x)\leqslant \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ ? Can we use this fact ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x = a$ is a solution to $f(x) = x$ , thus $f(a) = a$ . Now, take any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ . Without loss of generality, let $x \leqslant a$ . Then, by Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem, there exists $h_x \in (x , a)$ such that $$\left\vert \frac{f(x) - a}{x - a}\right\vert = \left\vert \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a}\right\vert = \vert f'(h_x) \vert \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$$ which is what you require to show.

Similarly, if $x \geqslant a$ , then an exactly similar calculation will show the same result. Therefore, for any given $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , we'll have : $$\left | f(x) - a \right | \leq \frac{1}{2} \left | x - a \right |$$

Sorry if I didn't understand your question properly.

Comment: Oh. I understood now. Thanks for the solution and the great explanation! I think it's correct yes!

Comment: You're welcome. In your problem, it was not necessary to specify any interval where $a$ lies. It would have been easier to understand if you stated that you had already found out that $| f'(x) | \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I already started that I found it to be smaller than 1/2, the thing is that I forgot to write absolute value. Sorry for that.